# Any way an apk deletes itself after it is installed?

Tags: android

I have made an app and for testing I want to give it to some friends for trying/testing. But I don't want them to pass it on to others. So is there a way that after installing the apk, the apk deletes itself?

Comment: Put an expiration date in your app.  Check the date when the app is opened, and close the app if the date on the phone is past the expiration date.

Comment: I think you can make it time based, date based!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install an apk, it is merely copied to the internal storage. Someone could always retrieve it from there easily enough.

There is no way to delete the apk they downloaded to install it, as you don't know where that apk is located on there phone. You could always show a dialog asking them to, or write some code into your app that sets an expiry date after which is stops working (like in the SwiftKey Flow Beta).

However, mostly handing out beta apks is a matter of trust. If you don't trust a tester to keep it private, don't give it to them.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
Can you tell me more about this expiry date thing? That would be helpful :)

Comment: @UjjwalSyal Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark if it answered your query.